# deployment of a web.config to amazon beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web.config-transform

When I deploy a .net web application to Amazon Beanstalk, my local web.config gets completely ignored and it just gets replaced with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PARAM3" value="" />
        <add key="PARAM4" value="" />
        <add key="PARAM1" value="" />
        <add key="PARAM2" value="" />
        <add key="PARAM5" value="" />
        <add key="AWS_SECRET_KEY" value="" />
        <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="" />
        <add key="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" value="" />
        <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I thought that beanstalk wasn't able to parse some section of my web.config so I simplified the web.config to the minimum:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mykey" value="myvalue"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And I get the same result. my appSettings and every other section of my web.config don't appear in the web.config that gets deployed.
I looked everywhere and I can't find documentation on this.
I don't have any transforms in my local application (i.e. no web.release.config file).
Can I disable this "feature" of Beanstalk somehow?

I don't ask for any action, I just want my original web.config deployed.

Comment: Are you deploying via Visual Studio or via awsdeploy.exe command line? If cmd line, share your parameters.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variables in the Elastic Beanstalk console, not in your git repository.

Comment: I am not trying to set any environment variable, I don't need them. The problem is that Amazon is replacing my whole web.config (including every other section like connectionstrings, modules, handlers etc) with the first web.config in my post above. I hope it is clear now. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: I edited my example showing that all sections are replaced, to avoid confusion.